# Adicionar HTTPS em site que não está na raiz

Tags: html, html5, wordpress, htaccess, https

Tenho um site que ele não está na raiz, ao entrar nele ele acrescenta /portal na frente do link pois ele é divido em pastas dentro da raiz, quando se acessa o /portal ele vai pra index do site e quando se acessa /news/nXX ele vai para uma newsletter do site. Geralmente para adicionar o HTTPS no site eu vou no arquivo htaccess e coloco o seguinte texto:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Porém, como não fui eu quem fez esse site, no htaccess dele já tem um monte de códigos (que redirecionam para o /portal quando se acessa a raiz), eu tentei acrescentar mas não obtive êxito.

Answer (score 1):

Descobri sozinho, mas vou deixar aqui a solução pra quem esteja passando pelo mesmo que eu passei:

Eu deveria estar indo no htaccess dentro da pasta portal e não dentro da raiz, fui lá nele e já estava o seguinte código:

```html
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /portal/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /portal/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# NOTE this account's php is controlled via FPM and the vhost, this is a place holder.
# Do not edit. This next line is to support the cPanel php wrapper (php_cli).
# AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .phtml
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

então eu só acrescentei as seguintes linhas acima da linha :

```html
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

e no final ficou assim:

```html
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /portal/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /portal/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# NOTE this account's php is controlled via FPM and the vhost, this is a place holder.
# Do not edit. This next line is to support the cPanel php wrapper (php_cli).
# AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .phtml
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```